# What means "Name=SWEIPS" Parametr in Siebel

Tags: http-post, loadrunner, siebel

Writing script in LR for Siebel Open UI. All my requests contains this parameter, with different values. What does it mean?

Examples (from different requests):

```
"Name=SWEIPS", Value = @0'0'1'0'GetProfileAttr'3'attrName'SBRF Position Id'"
"Name=SWEIPS", Value = @0'0''0'3'1-SQE21A, 1-SQL21E, 1SQE31"
```

And so on. 
Can I simple delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I simply delete it?** - No, you’re not supposed to delete it.

- Compare SWEIPS value by recording twice or trice with different data sets, check is there any date/time values in SWEIPS. If there is nothing to correlate leave as it is, no need to delete.
- Ensure to correlate values like SWET,ROWID,SWECount,SWEC and so on.